# Transfer function in nprtool

Tags: matlab, neural-network

may I know what is the transfer function used by MATLAB nprtool? Thank you and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The help indicates that it uses sigmoidal neurons. If you dig through the code (`edit nprtool` -> `edit patternnet`) you'll see that it appears to use the [hyperbolic tangent sigmoid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/tansig.html) transfer function.

Answer (score 1):

It's `tan-sigmoid` by default. [More info here.](http://www.mathworks.in/help/nnet/gs/recognizing-patterns.html#f9-48630)

Answer (score 1):

If you have already created your neural network you can see which function is being used in any layer by typing this command in the console:

> > mynet.layers{i}.transferFcn

...where 'mynet' is your net name and 'i' is an integer number pointing to a layer. This works for any standard multilayer architecture.